# Cloud function is unable to move files in archive bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have implemented an architecture as per the link https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions

But the issue is when multiple files come at the same time(For E:g. 3 files comes at the same timestamp(21/06/2020, 12:13:54 UTC+5:30)) in the bucket. In this scenario, the cloud function is unable to move all these files with the same timestamp to success bucket after processing.

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. So us code, example filenames and stats with timestamps. We can't duplicate the problem given the little you've told us, and to help you we must be able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage is not a file system. You can only CREATE, READ and DELETE the BLOB. Therefore, you can't MOVE a file. The MOVE that exist on the console or in some client library (in python for example) perform a CREATE (copy the existing BLOB to the target name) and then a DELETE of the old BLOB.

Eventually, you can't keep the original timestamp with you perform a MOVE operation.

*NOTE: because you perform a CREATE and a DELETE when you MOVE your file, you are charge on [early deletion](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing) when you use classes such as Nearline, coldline and archive*